how do resize first column width in ubuntu 24.04
In anutilus when we see list view; there are 4 columns displayed but the first column width is too wide and we can only change width of next columns and it only move reverse too;
so looking a away which adjust column width and able to adjust


Didn't you try to resize it from the end of it's width?

trid but it shrink the all columns but not first

yes you are rite, I just tried it. I think it might be possible by tweaking something in GTK themes css file. Can you try installing few gtk themes and that might give some visible clues of different widths for these columns. Then you can figure out which class is setting the width.

I dont want to add any theme but ys i have gnome tweak tool

Installing few themes I said bcoz it's easier to figure out visible changes and if that's working then you can remove those themes. This way is to find out which CSS class is responsible for first column width. Any ways you don't want to add that's fine.

I have no issue to install but problem I forsee that how to undo the things .. is it easy to install and change back? It would be helpful if you provide any link

https://itsfoss.com/install-themes-ubuntu/ for uninstalling gtk themes one easy way is to just remove the theme directory from installed location.

Nautilus' column width management is broken! This is one of the many bugs in recent versions of Nautilus. You can try to resize (expand) the other columns by dragging their right border to the right (not left)!.
